# Make sibling <div> visible using :checked css pseudo class with no javascript

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to follow the sample posted in [this](https://css-tricks.com/exposing-form-fields-radio-button-css/) article and I am unable to replicate the behaviour of having the new elements become visible after the radio button is checked.

```css
.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
  input[type="radio"]:checked {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transform: scale(1);
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Are you a student or a professional?</p>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="student" id="student">Student

  <div class="reveal-if-active">
    <p>Type of student:</p>
    <select name="student_types" data-require-pair="#student">
       <option display:none disabled selected value></option>
       <option value="highschool">High School</option>
       <option value="undergrad">Undergraduate</option>
       <option value="grad">Graduate</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using native `CSS`? as you cannot nest rules inside one another in native `CSS`. This is something used by `LESS`/`SCSS`/`SASS`/etc.

Comment: I am using native CSS. Is there a workaround in native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use selector `:checked + nextElSelector` ([Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)) to select element next to checked input:

```css
span {
  visibility: hidden;
}
input:checked + span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/><span>TADA!</span>
```

---

Your example CSS is actually SASS part of same site, except you removed some elements.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that I cannot structure native CSS the same way. Will accept in 3 mins

Answer (score 1):

Change your `input` selector to the following:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + .reveal-if-active {}
```

Note the `+`. This is the adjacent sibling selector and is necessary between the two in order to change the opacity of the hidden elements when the radio button is checked.

```css
.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + .reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transform: scale(1);
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<p>Are you a student or a professional?</p>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="student" id="student">Student

  <div class="reveal-if-active">
    <p>Type of student:</p>
    <select name="student_types" data-require-pair="#student">
      <option value="highschool">High School</option>
      <option value="undergrad">Undergraduate</option>
      <option value="grad">Graduate</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

below id updated snippet in native `CSS`

```css
.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;

}
  input[type="radio"]:checked {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transform: scale(1);
    overflow: visible;
  }
  
input[type="radio"]:checked + .reveal-if-active{
 opacity:1; 
 max-height:initial;
}
```

```html
<p>Are you a student or a professional?</p>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="student" id="student">Student

  <div class="reveal-if-active">
    <p>Type of student:</p>
    <select name="student_types" data-require-pair="#student">
       <option display:none disabled selected value></option>
       <option value="highschool">High School</option>
       <option value="undergrad">Undergraduate</option>
       <option value="grad">Graduate</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should look like this

```
 input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active{
```

Answer (score 0):

How is about using Jquery?
you will get know whether the radio button is checked or not by using this code. `$(this).is(':checked')` inside `change` function.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#student').on("change", function() {
    $('.reveal-if-active').css({
      'opacity': '1',
      'max-height': '100px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
  input[type="radio"]:checked {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transform: scale(1);
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Are you a student or a professional?</p>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="student" id="student">Student

  <div class="reveal-if-active">
    <p>Type of student:</p>
    <select name="student_types" data-require-pair="#student">
       <option display:none disabled selected value></option>
       <option value="highschool">High School</option>
       <option value="undergrad">Undergraduate</option>
       <option value="grad">Graduate</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```